# Управление потоком в WinAPI [СИ]

Tags: c, многопоточность, winapi, вывод, ввод

Вeчeр дoбpый
Нужно как-то из одного потока управлять другим потоком.
Читал, что есть CreatePipe и CreateEvent, но инфы очень мало и непонятно.
Может кто знает какой функцией говорить потоку: *создай дерево, вставь туды элемент 11, удали элемент 14* и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: И где можно об этом почитать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

enum CommandType {
    CREATE,
    APPEND,
    REMOVE,
    STOP
};

DWORD WINAPI receiver(LPVOID lpParameter) {
    MSG msg;
    // Создаём очередь до того, как в неё что-то пришлют
    PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE);

    // Сигнализируем о том, что поток создан и должным образом инициализирован
    SetEvent(lpParameter);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {  // Получаем сообщения из очереди
        if (WM_COMMAND == msg.message) {
            switch (msg.wParam) {
                case CREATE:
                    printf("Create tree\n");
                    break;
                case APPEND:
                    printf("Append %d\n", msg.lParam);
                    break;
                case REMOVE:
                    printf("Remove %d\n", msg.lParam);
                    break;
                case STOP:
                    return 0;
                default:
                    printf("Unknown command\n");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    HANDLE event;
    HANDLE thread;
    DWORD threadId;

    // Создание события инициализации потока
    event = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, "ThreadStarted");

    // Созданием потока и передача ему события
    thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, receiver, event, 0, &threadId);

    // Ожидание наступления события
    WaitForSingleObject(event, INFINITE);

    // Отправка в очередь сообщений команды на создание дерева
    PostThreadMessage(threadId, WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM) CREATE, (LPARAM) NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // Отправка в очередь сообщений команды на добавление элемента
        PostThreadMessage(threadId, WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM) APPEND, (LPARAM) i);
    }

    // Отправка в очередь сообщений команды на удаление элемента
    PostThreadMessage(threadId, WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM) REMOVE, (LPARAM) 1);

    // Отправка команды на завершение потока
    // и ожидание завершения в течении секунды,
    // чтобы он успел обработать последнее сообщение
    // до того, как основной поток завершит работу
    PostThreadMessage(threadId, WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM) STOP, (LPARAM) NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(thread, 1000);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!